# Error during Relion Installation, Cmake complains about shared library

Tags: cmake

I am trying to Install relion following the directions at https://github.com/3dem/relion.
I am getting the following error since some of the libraries will be shared. I am not sure how to address this issue.

```
WARNING: Target "particle_FCC" requests linking to directory "/home/../eman2-sphire-sparx/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "particle_FCC" requests linking to directory "/home/../eman2-sphire-sparx/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
CMake Warning at src/apps/CMakeLists.txt:208 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target particle_FCC because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libfftw3f.so.3] in /usr/lib64 may be hidden by files in:
      /home/../eman2-sphire-sparx/lib
    runtime library [libfftw3.so.3] in /usr/lib64 may be hidden by files in:
      /home/../eman2-sphire-sparx/lib
    runtime library [libpng16.so.16] in /usr/lib64 may be hidden by files in:
      /home/../eman2-sphire-sparx/lib
```

Comment: The [README](https://github.com/3dem/relion#readme) tells about many things. What **exact actions** you have done for build the project? It seems, some of these actions was wrong. E.g. setting some variable to `/home/../eman2-sphire-sparx/lib` was definitely wrong.

Comment: Was able to resolve this by: 1) removing eman2-sphire-sparx 2) removing all the directories for the Relion build 3) rebuild Relion. I may need to reinstall Eman2